# Excel logic for complex draw from different buckets without repeating bucket

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create an Excel file which can help me distribute 1944 coins into 648 bundles of 3 coins each.

The coins are coming from 10 buckets.
Bucket 1 contains Gold coins.
Buckets 2, 3 and 4 contain Silver coins.
Buckets 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 contain Bronze coins.

Here's a sheet with sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ORB2QrvPVHepTVRWhmvQg7asyl_aYQhs6_4Ae2IyQg/edit?usp=sharing

There are 2 distribution rules to be followed:

1. Each Bundle in the Bundles sheet must contain 3 coins from different buckets
2. Each Bundle in the Bundles sheet must contain either:

a) 1 Gold and 2 Bronze coins

b) 1 Silver and 2 Bronze coins

c) 3 Bronze coins

Any idea what formulas and logic I can use to automate the distribution while satisfying the rules?

Comment: Is this an homework?

Comment: Your data is inconsistent with your question: 3 gold, 3*49=147 silver, 6*199=1194 bronze; so total coins equates to 1344 (not 1944 as in the question). Which needs changing - question, data or both?

Comment: If you have x gold coins and y silver coins, you will have your first x+y bundles each with their first coin defined as either gold or silver. Now take 2*(x+y) bronze coins evenly from the 6 bronze buckets to fill the second and third coin slots for the gold and silver containing bundles. Assuming both x and y are integer multiples of 3, it will take 2*(x+y)=2*(3n+3m)=6*(n+m) bronze coins to fill up all the gold and silver bundles. Ie. the first (n+m) rows of the bronze buckets will be emptied fully. Assuming equal bronze buckets, B5-B7 make up the next set and B8-B10 the last set of bundles.

Comment: The above would make numerical assignment easy using MOD, ROW(), COLUMN() type functions. If however either of the above assumptions (multiple of 3 silver and gold, or equally distributed bronze buckets) are false, the outcome of the distribution is tricky and not guaranteed to have a proper solution.  As for a way to implement a generic "dealing" method (deck of card analogy) in Excel, it might he doable to keep track of a current r and c index to INDEX to the next available coin. As you are dealing out coins, r and c will increment to avoid blank cells in the coin bucket sheet.

Comment: @Toto No, it is for distributing rewards.

Comment: @DMM You are correct, I've fixed the data (I had stopped at 199 Bronze, when it should be 299)

Comment: @Mobus Multiple of 3 requirement is satisfied only for Gold (3), but not for Silver (49) nor Bronze (299). Can you create a simple version of the r and c tracking with INDEX to demonstrate?

Comment: The x and y identified by @Mobus are the total numbers of gold and silver coins not the size of the buckets, so x is 3 and  y is 147 (and both are multiples of 3). In fact, Mobus' condition can be relaxed to x+y being a multiple of 3 rather than x and y each being a multiple of 3 (though if latter is not true but the former is true then the  three silver buckets would necessarily have to be of different sizes).

Comment: Great, gold is always a multiple of 3! How about the distribution? Do we always have equal amounts of coins in each silver bucket (3x 49) and equal amounts in each bronze (6x 299)? That way Silver total is also a multiple of 3, and so it bronze total!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If x is the total gold coins (and a multiple of  3) the formulae for the first x rows (starting in row 2, columns B C and D) are

```
="B1-"&(ROW()-1)
="B"&(MOD((ROW()-2)*2+(COLUMN()-3), 6)+5)&"-"&(INT(((ROW()-2)*2+(COLUMN()-3))/6)+1)
="B"&(MOD((ROW()-2)*2+(COLUMN()-3), 6)+5)&"-"&(INT(((ROW()-2)*2+(COLUMN()-3))/6)+1)
```

Then with y the **total** silver coins across all three silver buckets and assuming equal distribution in each silver bucket, the next y rows must be

```
="B"& (INT((ROW()-2-x) / (y/3))+2) &"-"&(MOD((ROW()-2-x), y/3)+1)
="B"&(MOD((ROW()-2)*2+(COLUMN()-3), 6)+5)&"-"&(INT(((ROW()-2)*2+(COLUMN()-3))/6)+1)
="B"&(MOD((ROW()-2)*2+(COLUMN()-3), 6)+5)&"-"&(INT(((ROW()-2)*2+(COLUMN()-3))/6)+1)
```

From row x+y+1+1 and onwards, we will only deal from the bronze buckets. The last bronze coin delt in the previous row was (using substitution ROW = x+y+1 and COLUMN = 4)

```
"B"&(MOD((x+y+1-2)*2+(4-3), 6)+5)&"-"&(INT(((x+y+1-2)*2+(4-3))/6)+1)
```

Which simplifies to

```
"B"&(MOD((m+n)*6-1, 6)+5)&"-"&(INT(((m+n)*6-1)/6)+1)
```

With x=3*m and y=3*n and further simplifies to

```
"B10&"-"&(m+n)
```

Thus as said in the comments we have fully dealt out the first m+n rows of bronze coins.

From row x+y+1+1 onwards we will have then same formula in columns B C and D to deal the remaining bronze coins:

```
="B"&(MOD((ROW()-2)*3+(COLUMN()-2), 6)+5)&"-"&(INT(((ROW(A2)-2)*3+(COLUMN()-2))/6)+1+m+n)
```

I think. I havent tested these formula at all :))

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I've tested the formulae, they all work exactly as intended, and satisfy all rules!


--- I have two follow-up questions, which may be pushing it a bit :P 


--- Can the draw be "more random"? For example, a bundle with a gold coin now can never have B5 and B7 Bronze coins. (check the sample data sheet)


--- Can you create formulae where the amount of coins in all buckets are variables, the number of buckets are variables, and the number of outcome bundles are variables? (of course, all the variables will need to work as multiples, by default)

Comment: Haha yes that would be pushing it a little ;) But you can randomise the bundle numbers. Add a help column `=RAND()*1000`. Then add an auto-filter and sort ascending via the helper column. Then renumber column A. You might have to do this on a copy sheet where you paste as values. Dont destroy the formulae.

Comment: Another way to achieve some randomisation: Consider coin "B2-10" is currently in column 2 and row 10 of the data range CoinBuckets!$B$3:$K$301. Say you randomise the coin numbers on the CoinBuckets sheet (in much the same way as described in the comment above). Each bucket will contain its own coins but in random order. Now use the numerical parts of my original formulae as row and column indexes (coin position rather than coin number) and read the random coin from the randomised table e.g. `=INDEX(CoinBucket!$B$3:$K$301, *part that calcs the coin#*, *part that calc the bucket#*)`.

Comment: Thanks but both of these would not solve the issue that each bundle will still have more or less coins from the same buckets. The buckets will not be randomly picked.

Comment: Are you saying that its a problem that half the bronze-only buckets will essentially be from B5 B6 B7 and the other half from B6 B7 B8? Switching things up is difficult. Say you bundle at random, you might end-up with getting to the last bundle and sit with two coins from the same bucket.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need a solution that randomizes the buckets too, which makes me believe that this is either something that needs to be done with code that will iterate until finding a solution, or maybe using Solver?
But I'm stuck on the logic. I tried going in the direction of creating scenarios, e.g.:
If first coin is from Bucket B1, then options from there on are B5, B6, B7, B8, B9 and B10. 
Then if second is from B5, then the third one will be from B6, B7, B8, B9 and B10
et...but I'm having problem drawing unique coins. Is there a way for excel to mark what has been drawn already?

Comment: Well currently when we get to the bronze-only draw, we pick B5-B7 and then B8-B10, then progress to the next row. If you could randomly pick three buckets say B7, B5, B10 for the first draw and then automatically pick the remaining B8, B6 and B9 for the next, you would still clear out one "row" evenly.  Statistically every 2 bundle pair would be independent. I would use the same `=INDEX(...)` trick as per my comment, and rather renumber every row in the CoinBucket sheet. I hope you have Excel 365 `="B"&LET(x, RANDBETWEEN({0,0,0,0,0,0},100), MATCH(SMALL(x,{1,2,3,4,5,6}),x,0))+4&"-"&ROW()-1`

Comment: Any luck @kr3t3n? Could you try my above suggestion?